# Timber get_posts in template/view

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have an ACF field that allows a choice of post types, these are then going to be put in a carousel. There could be any number as every module on the page is controlled by the admin users.

In the carousel template, I want to be able to get the recent posts for the selected post type. I can to this with:

```
{% set items = fn('get_posts', {'post_type': 'team' }) %}
```

Is there a way to do this without calling it as a function? I was thinking along the lines of:

```
{% set items = Posts(params) %}
```

Is this possible or is the function call the only/best way?

Thanks

Comment: I think the cleanest way would be to get the extra posts defined by custom field in your controller file using TimberPost and pass it to the view.

Comment: is the ACF the relationship field? if so, treat it same as a repeater when calling in twig

Answer (score 1):

Currently, what you want to do is not possible. You could use `Timber::get_posts` through the array notation to get an array of Timber posts instead of regular WordPress posts:

```
{% set items = fn(['Timber\Timber', 'get_posts'], { 'post_type': 'team' }) %}
```

But in the future, the recommended way to get posts will be to use `Timber\PostQuery`. In the upcoming version 2 of Timber, we will add a `PostQuery` function to Twig. This means that you’ll be able to do something like this:

```
{% for items in PostQuery(params) %}
    {# Display item #}
{% endfor }
```

This would work well for simpler use cases. I’d also recommend what [Luckyfella](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704384/timber-get-posts-in-template-view#comment82424511_47704384) said, it may be better to not have this in Twig at all, but prepare everything in PHP and then pass the items on to the Twig view.

Comment: Looking forward to doing a PostQuery in Timber v2. I just tried your first code sample with Timber v1.10.0 and I had to change `fn(['Timber\Timber'` to `fn(['Timber` for it to work. Hope it helps someone else some day =)